# Laravel , Jquery fill data by selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Prolbem is When I select value of Dropdown. I want to fill that inputs by selected value. If that loops were static I can do that. How do I do that? Any suggestion?

**View**

```
<select id="target" style="text-align: center;" name="time"> 
    <option value="40">40 асуулт</option>
    <option value="50">50 асуулт</option>
    <option value="60">60 асуулт</option>
    <option value="70">70 асуулт</option>
    <option value="80">80 асуулт</option>
    <option value="90">90 асуулт</option>
</select>
```

**Looping data**

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
      <input class="qty1 form-control" value="0" type="number" min="0" 
 max="{{ $duplicate->total }}" step="1" name="number[{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}]"></input>
      </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: use ajax to get data from laravel on change select tag value.

Comment: then sir how do i set value of that looped inputs value?

Comment: do you want to fill same value which is selected would fill on all inputs ? or any single input ?

Comment: If i select 50questions. I want to fill up like 1st: 1 + 2nd: 4 + 3rd: 2 ... = 50.

Comment: all of inputs. equal 50.

Comment: Sorry , Your requirement is not clear, please update your question with  more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

When the value of select is changed, it will iterate through all element with class "qty1".

```
$('#target').change(function (){
   $('.qty1').each(function (index, element){
       element.val($('#target').val());
   })
})
```